# how can I see the latest git log info in an old clone?

Tags: git

I have a clone of my repo that is a few days old.  I have done a git pull to update it, but when I run git log, I don't see any of the new log entries that I see in a brand new clone.  I am trying to figure out what has changed between nightly builds by using the existing clone, but the log since= isn't showing me any changes because the log doesn't seem to get updated with a git pull or a git submodule update either.
Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: What's the `git branch -avv` output for both the old and new clones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` shows the log from the current HEAD.  If you are on some branch that is not `master`, your pull may not be updating the branch. You would have seen some message about being unable to merge.

Try `git checkout master` followed by `git pull` and then `git log`.

You could also try `git log origin/master` which will show you the log going backwards from your upstream clone source.

Answer (score 0):

See what is pulled down in terms of any branches with

```
git branch -r
```

then pick the ones you want to see in the log command:

```
git log origin/branch1 origin/branch2
```